# Compare Date from CSV Import To Get-Date

Tags: date, csv, powershell

I have a CSV that contains a number of columns but I want to import just the description column, a department column and a date column. I then want to create a new object with the description, department and date information but only for items that have a date 45 days or older. I know that the `Import-Csv` is bringing in the "Item Date" column as a string so that I need to use something like `Get-Date` or datetime to get it to a date format for comparison.

```
$data = import-csv .\items.csv | select "Description", "Department", "Item Date"
$CheckDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-45)
$data2 | Foreach  {get-date $_."Item Date"} |
    select "Description", "Department", "Item Date"
$newdata = $data2 | where {$data."Item Date" -lt $CheckDate}
```

There may be an easier way to do this or there may be a way to get this to work but I am having trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely some room for simplification here.

```
$CheckDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-45)
$data = Import-Csv .\items.csv | 
    Where-Object {
        ($_."Item Date" -as [DateTime]) -lt $CheckDate
    }
```

Just cast the "Item Date" string as a `[DateTime]` with the `-as` operator and then compare that to your `$CheckDate` in the `Where-Object` call.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the date format used in the CSV and the computer's regional settings simply casting the string to a `DateTime` value may or may not work. If you find that it doesn't use the [`ParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead. And perhaps a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx), since you're selecting columns anyway.

```
$fmt     = 'dd\/mm\/yyyy'
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

$data = Import-Csv .\items.csv |
        Select-Object Description, Department, @{n='Item Date';e={
          [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.'Item Date', $fmt, $culture)
        }} |
        Where-Object { $_.'Item Date' -lt $CheckDate }
```

Note that forward slashes in the format string must be escaped if you need to match literal forward slashes, otherwise they will match whatever date separator character is configured in the computer's regional settings.